# How to define global in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I would like to define TEST as global in XSD

```
          <xs:element name="TEST">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="TEST_LOGIN" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="DOCUMENT" type="xs:string" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top-level (children of `xs:schema`) component definitions are inherently globally available.

Nested definitions are only locally available – not referenceable elsewhere.

### See also

- [How to reference global types in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42421169/290085)
- [How to define a local type in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64099804/290085)